# Getting the raw Request in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc

I need to get the raw request string. Below is an example of the http request sent to the Controller. Actually, I need Post data (last line). How can I get that?

Notice that I don't want to use the automatic JSON model binder. Actually, I need the raw JSON text

```
POST http://www.anUrl.com/CustomExport/Unscheduled HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
Referer: http://www.anUrl.com/CustomExport
Accept-Language: en-us
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0)
Host: localhost:8000
Content-Length: 102
Connection: Keep-Alive
Pragma: no-cache

{"runId":"1","fileDate":"8/20/2012","orderStartMinDate":"10/02/2012","orderStartMaxDate":"10/02/2012"}
```

This last line is what I need. This doesn't come in

```
var input = new StreamReader(Request.InputStream).ReadToEnd();
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

At that point the stream has already been read to the end. You need to set the position of the InputStream back to the beginning before you can read it yourself.

```
Request.InputStream.Position = 0;
var input = new StreamReader(Request.InputStream).ReadToEnd();
```

Comment: Thank you, the problem was exactly that

Answer (score 2):

@louis-ricci's answer is correct, but bear in mind that if you use `[FromBody]` in your Action Method, you'll get exception when calling `Request.InputStream`, since `[FromBody]` already reads the request body in order to serialize to the model by invoking `HttpRequest.GetBufferlessInputStream()`, and this method can't be invoked twice. To get around this, simply **don't use** `[FromBody]` in your request and serialize the raw request string manually to your model.

**Edit:** For better context and search results on this topic, the error thrown has this message:

> This method or property is not supported after HttpRequest.GetBufferlessInputStream has been invoked