# Get the HTTP request and response raw for a specific page

Tags: c#, asp.net, http, httprequest

I've seen some threads about my problem but not exaclty what I need.

In my application, we have one page which centralizes all REST calls from outside.
This is our "endpoint" for our REST layer.
To have a good overview of what is entering and what is leaving from this endpoint, we want to log the request raw and the response raw at the HTTP layer.

The problem is that I'm in a complex architecture.
So, I can't implement a global solution (like IHttpModule with BeginRequest and EndRequest).

My question : is there a solution to capture ONLY the HTTP traffic for one page and with a "local" approach ?

NB : IIS trace or others loggers solutions are not allowed in my context.

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/a/12696631/34092 help?

Comment: The solution can be used for the request raw, yes. Thank you. But not for the response.

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1038466/logging-raw-http-request-response-in-asp-net-mvc-iis7 help?